# PowerShell pass values from table\csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture details of 3 devices x,y,and z.

To capture details of x. i have to run the script with below details.

exec script.ps1 x,x1,x2

x is device name
x1 is resource group
x2 is subscription

Table\csv has below details

x,x1,x2
y,y1,y2
z,z1,z2

How to i loop from x to z and pass their corresponding parameters from the table.

Normally i fetch the details like below

$servers = import-csv 'C:\arun.servers.csv'

foreach ($server in $servers)

{
..
}

But in this case i need to also get multiple parameters from the csv for $server.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: `exec` is not a native PowerShell command or alias. What does `script.ps1` contain?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) outputs [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances, each representing a CSV data row. These instances have properties named for the CSV file's columns (whose names are gleaned from the header row), and their values are the given data row's field values.

Therefore, in your `foreach` loop, you simply access the properties of interest in each iteration, corresponding to the given data row's column values.

The following assumes column names `Device`, `Group`, and `Subscription` - adjust as needed.
Should your CSV file lack a header row, supply the column names of choice via `Import-Csv`'s `-Header` parameter.

```bash
foreach ($server in Import-Csv C:\arun.servers.csv) {
  # Note: I'm assuming you need to pass the values *separately* (space-separated)
  #       not as a *single array* (","-separated)
  .\script.ps1 $server.Device $server.Group $server.Subscription
}
```